# i use .off() limit one click . but when next page button not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $(".questionPage").hide()

  let changeText = function(index) {
    $(".question").html(testMath[index].question);
    $("#option1").text(testMath[index].option[[0]]);
    $("#option2").text(testMath[index].option[[1]]);
  }

  let testMath = [{
      question: "1+2=?",
      option: ["3", "6"],
      answer: "3"
    },
    {
      question: "2+7=?",
      option: ["9", "13"],
      answer: "9"
    },
  ];

  let count = 0

  $("#start").click(function() {
    $(".questionPage").show();
    changeText(0);
  });

  $("#options button").click(function() {
    checkAnswer($(this))
  })

  let checkAnswer = function(option) {
    if (option.text() === testMath[count].answer) {
      console.log("answer = " + $(option).text())
      count++;
      console.log("count =" + count)
      $(option).text("correct").off("click");
      // .off("click") is keypoint,help me limit one chick
      // but have other problem.
      setTimeout(next, 5000);

      function next() {
        $(".questionPage").hide()

        changeText(1)
        $("#options button").on("click")
        // i hope button recovery click function work.
        // so use .on( ) recovery click but not work .                       
        $(".questionPage").show()
      }
    } else {
      $(option).text("wrong")
    }
  }



})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="start">start</button>

<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p class="question">1 + 2 = ?</p>
  <div id="options">
    <button id="option1">3</button>
    <button id="option2">6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

.off("click") is keypoint,help me limit one chick but have other problem.

i hope button recovery click function work.so use .on( ) recovery click but not work .

console.log not show answer and count when press correct botton on second page.

i use .off("click) limit one click

because when second times click bool become false .(because one time work and set text change).

Comment: Give me a minute I can get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments in the code...

```js
$(function() {

  // our test object
  let testMath = {
    1: {
      question: "1 + 2 = ?",
      options: [3, 6],
      answer: 3
    },
    2: {
      question: "2 + 7 = ?",
      options: [9, 13],
      answer: 9
    },
    3: {
      question: "10 + 4 = ?",
      options: [9, 13, 14, 5, 15],
      answer: 13
    }
  };

  // constant question page
  const questionPage = $('#questionPage');

  // render question function
  let renderQuestion = function(question) {

    // if question id exists in testMath object
    if (testMath[question]) {

      // render the question
      $('.question', questionPage).html(testMath[question].question);

      // remove old options
      $('.options',questionPage).empty();

      // for each question answer options
      testMath[question].options.forEach(function(answer) {

        // append answer option button to options
        $('.options',questionPage).append('<button data-question="' + question + '" data-answer="' + answer + '">' + answer + '</button>');

      });

    } else {

      // empty question page or what ever
      $(questionPage).empty();
      
      // test complete alert
      alert('Test Complete!');

    }
  }

  // each options button in question page click event
  $(questionPage).on('click', '.options BUTTON', function() {

    // get this button data values
    let question = $(this).data('question');
    let answer = $(this).data('answer');

    // check answer
    checkAnswer(this, question, answer);

  });

  // check answer function
  let checkAnswer = function(elem, question, answer) {

    // if answer is correct
    if (answer === testMath[question].answer) {

      // render this button text correct and switch off event 
      $(elem).text('correct').off('click');

      // 2 sec delay
      setTimeout(function() {

        // render next question
        nextQuestion(question);

      }, 2000);

    // else answer is wrong
    } else {

      // render this button text wrong
      $(elem).text("wrong");

      // 1 sec delay
      setTimeout(function() {

        // render wrong answer value back this button
        $(elem).text(answer);

      }, 1000);

    }

  }

  // next question function
  let nextQuestion = function(question) {

    // render next question
    renderQuestion(question + 1);

  }

  // document on click method to check for all matching targets
  $(document).on('click', '#start', function() {

    // show the question page
    $(questionPage).show();

    // render question id 1
    renderQuestion(1);

    // remove start button
    $(this).remove();

  });

});
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>

<div id="questionPage" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p class="question"></p>
  <div class="options"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: No worries, hope it gets you on the right track 