# How use .off("click") after recovery this click event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  $(this).text("word")
  test($(this))
})

function test(one) {
  one.off("click")
  // other code ... may be 100 row//
  // ....
  //"here" recovey click . but how ?
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p>hello</p>
```

.off("click") is keypoint,help me limit one chick but have other problem.

i hope last code recovery click function work.so use .on( ) recovery click but not work .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following you right..

Are you trying to disable the clicked `P` `.on` event using `.off`, but then re-bind `.on` to the last clicked `P` when another `P` is clicked?

```js
$('p').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('on P clicked');
  $(this).text('word');
  $(this).off('click').addClass('off');
})
```

```css
P:not(.off):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: re-enabled only one  p not another  .

Comment: In my demo all `p` are binded with `.on('click')` event, but when you click a `p`, this `.on` event is switched `.off`... and all other `p` remain `.on` until clicked... what do you need to happen with the previous clicked `p` targets?

Comment: i set random question and options . will button context become question option for different but is complex. so simplify to this post .my random question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481278/i-use-off-limit-one-click-but-when-next-page-button-not-work